# How to put data of each month in its respective monthly column

Tags: php, date

I'm still learning, please help me

I have this code that will show monthly statistics. How do I put each data of each month in its respective column?

This is what I got so far.

```
$result= $myDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$myDB->prefix("statistics")." WHERE year='2017'") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = $myDB->fetchArray($result))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$year=$row['year'];
$sum=$row['sum'];
$january=$row['january'];
$february=$row['february'];
$march=$row['march'];
$april=$row['april'];
$may=$row['may'];
$june=$row['june'];
$july=$row['july'];
$august=$row['august'];
$september=$row['september'];
$october=$row['october'];
$november=$row['november'];
$december=$row['december'];
}


echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><thead><tr>";

echo "<th class='text-center'>Year</th>";
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br>';
echo "<th class='text-center'>$monthName</th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='text-center'>$year</td>";

for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
echo "<td class='text-center'> data </td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are storing data in month name vaiable you can get it using `$$` try this:

```
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><thead><tr>";

echo "<th class='text-center'>Year</th>";
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
echo "<th class='text-center'>$monthName</th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='text-center'>$year</td>";

for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=strtolower(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)));
echo "<td class='text-center'>".$$monthName." </td>";
}
```